# Evaluation self notebook with loop

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, procedural-programming

I have a large notebook with multiple sections. I would like to run the entire notebook with one variable change kquads.
At the end of the notebook, I added one loop

```
Do[(Clear @@ DeleteCases[Names@"`*", "kquad" | "i"]; 
  kquad = 3.190597 + 3.190597 0.01 i; Print[kquad]; 
  NotebookEvaluate@EvaluationNotebook[]), {i, -2, 2, 1}]
```

However, this loop looks i always equals to -2. Probably, the selfevaluation also initial this command as well, set i =-2... How could I make i equals to -2,-1,0,1,2?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.
Make a separate notebook and do this loop. It works.

```
    kini = 3.190597;
nstep = 0.02
n = 5
Table[NotebookEvaluate[
  "/Users/wange/Documents/Research/strong hadron cooling/lattice \
design/MBI/MBreduce/MB reduce.nb"], {kquad, kini - n nstep kini , 
  kini + n nstep kini, nstep kini }]
```